# Why does this user have a negative tag score on MSO, but not on MSE?

Tags: support, meta, tag-score

I found a user that has a net negative post score on both MSO and MSE. On MSO, the user has a negative tag score:

[image]

However, on MSE, the score is not negative (screenshot from MSE):

[image]

Is the tag score on global meta computed differently?

Comment: Those are some mighty fine scores right there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're also possible on Meta Stack Exchange:

[image]

(I'm not going to link to that profile, it should be relatively easy to find an example yourself.)

The difference between the profile above and the one from your screenshot is that this user actually posted a negatively scoring *answer* in those tags. While questions do determine which tags are displayed in a user profile, they don't count for the displayed tag *score*; only answers do.