# Why was this "No longer needed" on a comment flag declined?

Tags: discussion, comments, meta, declined-flags, comment-flags

The question [Why does this user have a negative tag score on MSO, but not on MSE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334410/336163) was asked earlier this month here on Meta Stack Exchange, asking why a particular user had zero tag score on one site but *negative* tag score on another. One user posted a good answer, while another posted the following comment:

> Those are some mighty fine scores right there.

That comment struck me as a somewhat insensitive use of irony. It didn't strike me as sufficiently rude to warrant an *unfriendly or unkind* flag, but it did seem chatty and tangential, so I flagged it as "no longer needed". My flag was declined.

> no longer needed – Robert Columbia Oct 4 at 19:21   declined

No particular moderator message was provided to help me understand *why* it was declined.

Where did I go wrong here? Are comments such as these that look like mildly condescending jokes, but do not rise to the level of harassment, allowed or encouraged?

Comment: As the comment flagging FAQ says, moderators cannot provide a reason for declining a comment flag, and marking a comment flag as helpful requires them to also delete the comment, so borderline flags will be marked declined.

Comment: If you think that perhaps one of the options for the flag isn't the right choice, because it's borderline, then you can also use the Something Else option, and put a more descriptive reason in there. Sometimes extra information is needed, if a comment on it's own, with the flag "no longer needed" doesn't really really give the full picture.